# Getting strange TypeError from my function

Tags: python

I'm getting an error (`TypeError: add_movie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'`) on a function of mine and can't figure out why. I'm assuming I'm missing something stupid/small again.  I can see that the function does indeed have the named param `title`.  Every other similar question I've read was missing the offending param from the function - this one, however, is not.
All of the code below is in the same file.

**main.py:**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float

URL_MOVIE_META = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "It's a secret"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'movie'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    year = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    rating = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    ranking = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    review = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    img_url = Column(String(250))

def add_movie(title, year, description, rating, ranking, review, img_url):
    global db
    movie = Movie(
        title=title,
        year=year,
        description=description,
        rating=rating,
        ranking=ranking,
        review=review,
        img_url=img_url
    )
    db.session.add(movie)
    db.session.commit()
...

def get_metadata_for_movie(tmdb_id):
    params = {
        "api_key": TMDB_API_KEY,
    }
    response = requests.get(f'{URL_MOVIE_META}/{tmdb_id}', params=params)
    data = response.json()
    year = datetime.strptime(data['release_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').year

    add_movie(
        title=data['title'],
        year=year,
        description=data['overview'],
        rating=0,
        ranking=0,
        review='',
        img_url=f'{URL_POSTER_PREFIX}/{data["poster_path"]}'
    )
...

@app.route("/")
def home():
    movies = get_all_movies()
    return render_template("index.html", movies=movies)

@app.route('/add/<tmdb_id>')
def add_movie(tmdb_id):
    get_metadata_for_movie(tmdb_id)
    print(f'{tmdb_id}')
    # Add movie...?
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

The error:

```
TypeError: add_movie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'
```

EDIT: added more example code

Comment: Is `add_movie()` a method of class?

Comment: @OlvinRoght If it were a method, he wouldn't be able to call it as `add_movie(...)` without an object before it.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - it is not part of a class.  Just a basic function.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: Until you show a [mre] we can only guess and nobody will know the real problem.

Comment: @Nandostyle, doubt that.

Comment: I've added more example code. Please let me know if more is needed and where from.

Comment: `def add_movie(tmdb_id):` this function doesn't take an argument called 'title'.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I feel like such an idiot for missing that.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the "global db" line is useless, because it only allows you to reassign db from your function, but you're only getting attributes from it and then calling methods on these attributes, which is totally legal without declaring it as global. For the solution to your problem, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second add_movie function is overriding the first one, so Python tells you that the current definition doesn't accept a keyword argument named "title" - and it's true, since the only argument is "tmbd_id".